# Can a Barbarian self-inflict damage to keep raging?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, barbarian, rage

In D&D 5e, the barbarian's [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage-51) is somewhat different from its 3.5e counterpart, but the thing that most confused me is the need to be actively part of mayhem and destruction at every round to keep being angry (emphasis mine):

> Your rage lasts for 1 minute. It **ends early** if you are knocked unconscious or **if your turn ends and you haven't attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then**. You can also end your rage on your turn as a bonus action.

Can a barbarian (with or without a shield) punch/stomp/bite/headbutt itself to take damage and maintain their rage?

To me, it seems its possible by RAW, but I'm not sure about the rules intent on whether an unmissable attack (I refuse to think that you can miss when trying to hit yourself if you are not heavily drunk) with the lowest melee damage possible from a Barbarian can keep you raging for the full duration.

Comment: Related: [Anger management: How to keep raging](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50974/52137)

Comment: Related, probably a dupe: [Does poking yourself with a needle with the intent to do damage require the Attack action, or can it be done as a (free) object interaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159174/)

Comment: @enkryptor: It's related, but definitely not a duplicate; the linked question just assumes it's possible already and asks what kind of action it'd be, whereas this question is asking whether it's possible (i.e. whether it meets the requirement for Rage).

Comment: @V2Blast if it wasn't possible, the linked answer would say this, I guess

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, a Barbarian can self-inflict damage to keep their Rage going.

It shows this right in the rules text you quoted:

> **It ends early if** you are knocked unconscious or if **your turn ends and you haven't** attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or **taken damage since then.**

There is no qualifier to who or what caused the damage, only that you took any.

Keep in mind that, no matter how much you might refuse to believe it, there is **no RAW** to suggest you can self inflict damage for free in any way. The only allowed mechanics to attack yourself are by making an actual roll, which means you're sacrificing an attack and you could fail to "hit" (read: meaningfully hurt) yourself. It's not that easy to hurt yourself.

(Much easier to set yourself on fire.)

Comment: I meant full duration, but I changed it anyways :)

Related to setting yourseld on fire, if you are a Bear Totem Barbarian and the fire deals 1 damage, it becomes 0 (due to resistances), and I'm not sure if 0 damage is damage.

Comment: It's also usually easier to attack a hostile creature, under normal circumstances (although I realise that there are potential uses for Rage outside of combat) - because in that case you don't need to hit, just to attack.

Comment: *"Yes, a Barbarian can self-inflict damage to keep their Rage going."* — Could you back this up with any citation of game text?

Comment: @enkryptor It seems difficult to prove a negative... The section quoted in the question (PHB p.48) says "It ends early ... if your turn ends and you haven't ... taken damage since then". It doesn't say that the damage must come from a creature other than yourself.

Comment: @DM_with_secrets I'm not talking about out of combat situations, but situations when you can't reach an opponent (like a temporary flight or invisibility), but you know the combat isn't finished, and attacking them with a retoric curse doesn't seem neither barbaric nor legal by raw xD

Comment: @MrTakeru Okay, cool. Depending how far it's flown, you could still throw a javelin at it, and I'm pretty sure you can still try to attack an invisible creature, just with disadvantage (although I don't have a reference for that just now, sorry). But I still agree with this answer that you can damage yourself if you want/need to :)

Comment: Plus, if you set yourself on fire, ninjas can't grab you.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Ninjas are way too cool to be burned in that way.

Comment: It seems a weird ruling that you'd have to defeat your own AC with a normal combat roll to self-harm. If its not automatic, it seems like you should at least get the advantage one would get attacking a (melee) prone, unconscious, or otherwise unresisting target.

Comment: @T.E.D. you can rule either way. It's not easy to stab yourself, you're fighting off a billion years of evolution to do so, so it's also reasonable to rule the roll is with disadvantage. Whatever you pick is defensible, so it's really up to the DM/table and the story being told.

Comment: Re: "there is no RAW to suggest you can self inflict damage for free in any way. The only allowed mechanics to attack yourself are by making an actual roll".  Actually, the RAW for this are in the DMG under 'Using Ability Scores' and say "When deciding whether to use a roll, ask yourself...Is a task so easy and so free of conflict and stress that there should be no chance of failure?"  If a DM considers that it is so easy to damage yourself that no roll is required, then no roll is required.